# tf-idf для запроса

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, nltk, естественный-язык

У меня есть запрос, состоящий из слов, и тексты. Для каждого слова я рассчитал tf-idf по текстам. Как теперь упорядочить тексты по релевантности запросу? Достаточно ли просто сранить суммы tf-idf-ов для всех слов запроса? Нормированные суммы? Максимальный tf-idf? Что-то другое?

Comment: Если я правильно соображаю, вам надо сложить tf-idf тех слов запроса, которые нашлись в тексте. И вот из этих сумм взять максимальную. Соответствующий этой сумме текст и будет наиболее релевантным

Comment: А вообще я давно занимался, как-то это автоматом же делается

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю ранжировать документы по отношению к запросу с помощью косинусного расстояния. Если размерность вектора запроса и вектора текста одинаковая, то просто рассчитывается скалярное произведение этих векторов и делится на их длины. А затем эти произведения ранжируются по возрастанию "угла" между документом и запросом. То есть, чем меньше угол, тем ближе документ к требуемому запросу. :)

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду под "размерностью"? Эмбеддинги у них в одном пространстве будут, иначе что тут вообще считать. И матрицы будут разреженные, но это не мешает считать косинус, а даже ускоряет подсчёт.

Comment: Судя из заголовка вопроса, речь идёт о tf-idf, а не об эмбеддингах. Что касается размерности, имеется в виду то, что запрос надо приводить к вектору такой же длины, как и векторы документов в разреженной матрице :)